# Rspec controller not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run a unit testing on my API controllers in Rails. But it's not behaving like I thought it should.

This line works:

```
post '/api/sessions', params
```

This line however

```
post :create, params
```

will throw error

```
Failure/Error: post :create
 URI::InvalidURIError:
   bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80create
```

I can use the first one, but would be good to know why doesn't the 2nd syntax works? Because I remember using that syntax in previous projects, and it works. I don't remember any special setup on my RSpec config.

Update: My codes

Api::ApiController

```
class Api::ApiController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

Api::SessionsController

```
module Api
  class SessionsController < Api::ApiController
    def create
      # find user and store in @user. I'm using jbuilder
      render status: 201
    end
  end
end
```

RSpec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Api::SessionsController, :type => :controller do
  describe '#POST' do
    it 'should retrieve user' do
      post '/api/sessions', params # this works
      post :create, params # this fails
    end
  end
end
```

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  apipie
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'    

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :sessions, only: [:create]
    resources :users, only: [:create]
    resources :trips, only: [:create]
  end
end
```

Based on the comment, I run `raise method(:post).source_location.inspect` at the beginning of the test, and this is what I get.

For this project, which currently failed:

```
RuntimeError:
   ["/Users/tokwan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb", 335]
```

And for other project, where `post :create` works:

```
RuntimeError:
   ["/Users/tokwan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb", 513]
```

Comment: Can you post some more relevant lines of the spec and your controller code? It's hard to see what's going wrong by a single line (which looks okay, so the actual issue might be in the controller)

Comment: @fivedigit Just updated my questions with my codes

Comment: Can you add your routes file? This may be an issue with routing

Comment: @NateSHolland Just added my routes as well

Comment: Which version of RSpec are you using? Your Gemfile.lock should tell you.

Comment: @yez currently using rspec 3.4.0

Comment: What's the real value for `example.com`  ? Is that domain configured somewhere ?

Comment: Are other controller tests working correctly? Do you have `rspec-rails` gem in your Gemfile? If so, please add `raise method(:post).source_location.inspect` at the beginning of the test and paste what you'll get.

Comment: @BroiSatse It's a bit long, so I've updated my questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: It sounds like you thing you are running a controller spec, but actually you are running a request spec.

Rspec can find out the type of a spec through 2 mechanisms: If you tell it in the metadata for the example / example group,

```
describe "something", type: :controller  do
  ..
end
```

or based on file location, if you have `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in your spec helper. It looks like your spec is tagged as controller, but it sounds like something is overriding it: perhaps it's in the wrong location, or something else is changing its type.

As a recap, the differences between controller & requests specs:

### Controller specs

These live in spec/controllers, with `type: controller`. Rails calls these [functional tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers), but they are basically unit tests for individual controllers (especially with rspec, which by default skips the rendering of views).

Each spec tests a single invocation of a controller action. The invocation of the action doesn't use routing (although I think it is an error these days if there is no route mapped to the action). Rails provides helpers that will invoke the specified action with any desired parameters, e.g. `get action: 'show', id: 1`. Rack Middlewares and so on are skipped.

### Request specs

These live in `spec/requests`, `spec/api`, and
`spec/integration`. Rails calls them [integration tests](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing). These can span multiple requests and run through the entire middleware stack, render views etc. This isn't just a test of a single controller so you specify a path, rather than just an action, e.g. `get '/articles/1'`

Comment: So it seems like this is the problem. For a quick fix, I just moved my `spec/api` folder to `spec/controllers/api` since in that location, RSpec will automatically detect that those are `controller` tests, not `requests`